# Get Struct property using String variable after initialising Struct instance

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I hope the code and comments below illustrate what I'm trying to learn how to do.

Accessing Struct property named iphone, I can, it's valid to :

```
IconSizes().iphone
```

Accessing Struct property named iphone, I can't and want to access it using a variable containing a String value "iPhone" :

```
IconSizes().selectedIconType
```

In more context :

```
selectedIconType = "iphone" // already set as String

let sizesNamesArray = IconSizes().selectedIconType // obviously raises error.
```

The Struct :

```
struct IconSizes {
    var typesList: Array<String>

    var iphone: [Dictionary<String, Any>]

    init() {
        self.typesList = ["iPhone"]

        self.iphone = [
            ["size":16,"name":"icon_small.png"],
            ["size":32,"name":"icon_small@2x.png"],
            ["size":32,"name":"icon_medium.png"],
            ["size":64,"name":"icon_medium@2x.png"],
            ["size":64,"name":"icon_large.png"],
            ["size":128,"name":"icon_large@2x.png"],
            ["size":128,"name":"icon.png"],
            ["size":256,"name":"icon@2x.png"]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code around what you're trying to do? preferably just post your struct. It's impossible to tell what IconSizes().selectedIconType is supposed to be.

Comment: selectedIconType is just a string "iPhone" I need to make that at my best guess, some sort of literal, so I can say : IconSizes.selectedIconType

Comment: What's the end result you're looking for? What would end up in sizedNamesArray?

Comment: The dictionary array from the struct, containing the sizes and names. (the Structs iphone property).

Comment: is an `enum` an option?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a constant within your app? or something that's dynamically created?

Comment: Still leaves me with the same question. How to use the value of my selectedIconType variable in the call to, a Struct or an Enum.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing names of variables at run time as if they were strings is usually easy in interpreted languages and less so as you move to compiled, static languages.  Being explicit is likely to work better.

```
struct IconSizes {
    var typesList: Array<String>

    var iphone: [Dictionary<String, Any>]
    var types = [String : [Dictionary<String, Any>]]()

    init() {
        self.typesList = ["iPhone"]

        self.iphone = [
            ["size":16,"name":"icon_small.png"],
            ["size":32,"name":"icon_small@2x.png"],
            ["size":32,"name":"icon_medium.png"],
            ["size":64,"name":"icon_medium@2x.png"],
            ["size":64,"name":"icon_large.png"],
            ["size":128,"name":"icon_large@2x.png"],
            ["size":128,"name":"icon.png"],
            ["size":256,"name":"icon@2x.png"]
        ]
        self.types["iPhone"] = self.iphone
    }
}

let selectedIconType = "iPhone"
print(IconSizes().types[selectedIconType])
```

Comment: Thank you Philip. I thought it would be as simple as casting my string variable in some way to be able to use it in the call to the struct, but your answer works for me, and makes total sense.